# Calculate Column with Rolling Max Value Based on Boolean Column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to perform a new column calculation WITHOUT using a `for` loop (using OHLC stock data) that denotes the rolling highest high, based on the `True` value in another column. I've denoted a "first hour of trading" time window to be between 9:30 and 10:30. During that time, as we iterate through the rows, if `"first hour of trading" == True`, and the current High is >= the previous High, then use that newer high. If we're NOT inside the "first hour of trading", just bring forward the previous value.

So, using this reproducible dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Create a reproducible, static dataframe.
# 1 minute SPY data. Skip to the bottom...
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:30",
        "open": "457.2",
        "high": "457.29",
        "low": "456.78",
        "close": "456.9383",
        "volume": "594142"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:31",
        "open": "456.94",
        "high": "457.07",
        "low": "456.8",
        "close": "456.995",
        "volume": "194061"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:32",
        "open": "456.99",
        "high": "457.22",
        "low": "456.84",
        "close": "457.21",
        "volume": "186114"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:33",
        "open": "457.22",
        "high": "457.45",
        "low": "457.2011",
        "close": "457.308",
        "volume": "294158"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:34",
        "open": "457.31",
        "high": "457.4",
        "low": "457.25",
        "close": "457.32",
        "volume": "172574"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:35",
        "open": "457.31",
        "high": "457.48",
        "low": "457.18",
        "close": "457.44",
        "volume": "396668"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:36",
        "open": "457.48",
        "high": "457.6511",
        "low": "457.44",
        "close": "457.57",
        "volume": "186777"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:37",
        "open": "457.5699",
        "high": "457.73",
        "low": "457.5699",
        "close": "457.69",
        "volume": "187596"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:38",
        "open": "457.7",
        "high": "457.73",
        "low": "457.54",
        "close": "457.63",
        "volume": "185570"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:39",
        "open": "457.63",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.31",
        "close": "457.59",
        "volume": "164707"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:40",
        "open": "457.59",
        "high": "457.72",
        "low": "457.46",
        "close": "457.7199",
        "volume": "167438"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:41",
        "open": "457.72",
        "high": "457.8",
        "low": "457.68",
        "close": "457.72",
        "volume": "199951"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:42",
        "open": "457.73",
        "high": "457.74",
        "low": "457.6",
        "close": "457.62",
        "volume": "152134"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:43",
        "open": "457.6",
        "high": "457.65",
        "low": "457.45",
        "close": "457.5077",
        "volume": "142530"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:44",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.4001",
        "close": "457.61",
        "volume": "122575"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:45",
        "open": "457.61",
        "high": "457.76",
        "low": "457.58",
        "close": "457.75",
        "volume": "119886"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:46",
        "open": "457.74",
        "high": "457.75",
        "low": "457.37",
        "close": "457.38",
        "volume": "183157"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:47",
        "open": "457.42",
        "high": "457.49",
        "low": "457.37",
        "close": "457.44",
        "volume": "128542"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:48",
        "open": "457.43",
        "high": "457.49",
        "low": "457.33",
        "close": "457.44",
        "volume": "154181"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:49",
        "open": "457.43",
        "high": "457.5898",
        "low": "457.42",
        "close": "457.47",
        "volume": "163063"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:50",
        "open": "457.45",
        "high": "457.59",
        "low": "457.44",
        "close": "457.555",
        "volume": "96229"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:51",
        "open": "457.56",
        "high": "457.61",
        "low": "457.31",
        "close": "457.4217",
        "volume": "110380"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:52",
        "open": "457.42",
        "high": "457.56",
        "low": "457.42",
        "close": "457.47",
        "volume": "107518"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:53",
        "open": "457.475",
        "high": "457.51",
        "low": "457.4",
        "close": "457.48",
        "volume": "78062"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:54",
        "open": "457.49",
        "high": "457.57",
        "low": "457.42",
        "close": "457.46",
        "volume": "133883"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:55",
        "open": "457.47",
        "high": "457.56",
        "low": "457.45",
        "close": "457.51",
        "volume": "98998"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:56",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.54",
        "low": "457.43",
        "close": "457.43",
        "volume": "110237"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:57",
        "open": "457.43",
        "high": "457.65",
        "low": "457.375",
        "close": "457.65",
        "volume": "98794"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:58",
        "open": "457.66",
        "high": "457.69",
        "low": "457.35",
        "close": "457.45",
        "volume": "262154"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:59",
        "open": "457.45",
        "high": "457.47",
        "low": "457.33",
        "close": "457.4",
        "volume": "74685"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:00",
        "open": "457.41",
        "high": "457.48",
        "low": "457.18",
        "close": "457.38",
        "volume": "166617"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:01",
        "open": "457.39",
        "high": "457.7",
        "low": "457.39",
        "close": "457.5",
        "volume": "265649"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:02",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.57",
        "low": "457.39",
        "close": "457.53",
        "volume": "131947"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:03",
        "open": "457.53",
        "high": "457.54",
        "low": "457.4",
        "close": "457.51",
        "volume": "80111"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:04",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.62",
        "low": "457.5",
        "close": "457.6101",
        "volume": "117174"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:05",
        "open": "457.621",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.51",
        "close": "457.58",
        "volume": "168758"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:06",
        "open": "457.58",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.46",
        "close": "457.61",
        "volume": "84076"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:07",
        "open": "457.62",
        "high": "457.7401",
        "low": "457.62",
        "close": "457.66",
        "volume": "125156"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:08",
        "open": "457.665",
        "high": "457.69",
        "low": "457.5",
        "close": "457.67",
        "volume": "116919"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:09",
        "open": "457.69",
        "high": "457.72",
        "low": "457.5",
        "close": "457.57",
        "volume": "102551"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:10",
        "open": "457.56",
        "high": "457.75",
        "low": "457.56",
        "close": "457.7",
        "volume": "109165"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:11",
        "open": "457.7",
        "high": "457.725",
        "low": "457.63",
        "close": "457.66",
        "volume": "146209"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:12",
        "open": "457.665",
        "high": "457.88",
        "low": "457.64",
        "close": "457.86",
        "volume": "210620"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:13",
        "open": "457.855",
        "high": "457.96",
        "low": "457.83",
        "close": "457.95",
        "volume": "159975"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:14",
        "open": "457.95",
        "high": "458.02",
        "low": "457.93",
        "close": "457.95",
        "volume": "152042"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:15",
        "open": "457.96",
        "high": "458.15",
        "low": "457.96",
        "close": "458.08",
        "volume": "146047"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:16",
        "open": "458.085",
        "high": "458.17",
        "low": "457.99",
        "close": "458.15",
        "volume": "100732"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:17",
        "open": "458.17",
        "high": "458.33",
        "low": "458.155",
        "close": "458.245",
        "volume": "235072"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:18",
        "open": "458.25",
        "high": "458.29",
        "low": "458.14",
        "close": "458.16",
        "volume": "422002"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:19",
        "open": "458.17",
        "high": "458.2801",
        "low": "458.1699",
        "close": "458.28",
        "volume": "114611"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:20",
        "open": "458.29",
        "high": "458.39",
        "low": "458.24",
        "close": "458.37",
        "volume": "241797"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:21",
        "open": "458.37",
        "high": "458.42",
        "low": "458.31",
        "close": "458.345",
        "volume": "124824"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:22",
        "open": "458.33",
        "high": "458.49",
        "low": "458.33",
        "close": "458.47",
        "volume": "132125"
    }
])
```

... and this code which can go below the above df:

```
# Convert df to numeric and time to datetime re: the .csv to .json
# converter tool I used online...
df[['open','high','low','close','volume']] = df[['open','high','low','close','volume']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# When will the first hour of trading be?
startOfFirstHourTrading = datetime.strptime("0930", "%H%M").time()
endOfFirstHourTrading = datetime.strptime("1030", "%H%M").time()

# ...then using those times, define a boolean column denoting whether
# we're currently in the first hour of trading or not
df['isFirstHourTrading'] = np.where((df['time'].dt.time >= startOfFirstHourTrading) & (df['time'].dt.time < endOfFirstHourTrading), True, False)

df['FirstHourHigh'] = 0

# WORKING EXAMPLE
# Iterate through the df
for i in range(len(df)):

    # If we're not currently within the first hour of trading, just
    # bring forward the last value
    if df['isFirstHourTrading'].iloc[i] == False:
        df['FirstHourHigh'].iloc[i] = df['FirstHourHigh'].iloc[i-1]
        continue

    # ... otherwise if we ARE in the first hour of trading, keep track
    # of the rolling highest high during the first hour
    df['FirstHourHigh'].iloc[i] = max(df['high'].iloc[i], df['high'].iloc[i-1])

# Export the correct answer dataset to compare the next function
# to below
df.to_csv("correct_answers.csv", index=False)

# NON-WORKING EXAMPLE
# What I'd like to do is NOT use a for loop to do the above. I envision
# we can use np.where() and maybe a groupby() here? But I don't know how yet. 
# Psuedo might look something like:
df['FirstHourHigh'] = df['high'].rolling(window=DYNAMIC_START_OF_FIRST_HOUR_TRADING_ROW?).max()
# ... but obviously doesn't work, and doesn't take into account if if df['isFirstHourTrading'] == True which it should

# Cross check for matches with correct_answers.csv
df.to_csv("correct_answers2.csv", index=False)
```

...you'll see that I've implemented what I want using a `for` loop, to compare what I'm looking for to afterward. I'm looking to achieve the same thing as the `for` loop but without using a for loop, just using a 1 line column calculation. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get time as time, then mask values in the first trading hour, get their cumulative max, and bring the last (thus highest) values forward:

```
>>> df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
>>> first_hour = (df['time'].dt.hour * 60 + df['time'].dt.minute).between(9.5 * 60, 10.5 * 60)
>>> df['high'].where(first_hour).cummax().ffill()
```

Here’s what it does on a smaller example that actually has several days and dates otuside of the first order too:

```
>>> df
                 time  high
0 2021-10-26 09:30:00   525
1 2021-10-26 10:00:00   504
2 2021-10-26 10:30:00   550
3 2021-10-26 11:00:00   567
4 2021-10-27 09:30:00   520
5 2021-10-27 10:00:00   576
6 2021-10-27 10:30:00   508
7 2021-10-27 11:00:00   532
>>> df['high'].where((df['time'].dt.hour * 60 + df['time'].dt.minute).between(9.5 * 60, 10.5 * 60)).cummax().ffill()
0    525.0
1    525.0
2    550.0
3    550.0
4    550.0
5    576.0
6    576.0
7    576.0
```

Answer (score 1):

pandas cummax function can be used over the isFirstHourTrading high column, as follows:

```
df["FirstHourHigh"] = (df["isFirstHourTrading"]*df["high"]).cummax()
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, it's probably expected that you have a lot of data that doesn't fit the criteria of `"first hour of trading" == True`, right? If that's the case we can start by filtering out that data so that we don't need to deal with the other case.

```
firstHourTrading = df[df["isFirstHourTrading"] == True]
```

If that's not a option that's okay too. We can instantly increase performance of the loop by using apply and using the previous row using the same algorithm you used in your for loop.

```
df.apply(lambda row: your_business_logic(row, row.shift()))
```

Alternatively you can try to use `cummax` function from pandas if that will suit your needs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html